# Detecting `<Enter>` and `<Leave>` events for a frame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a menu which when the user moves their mouse off I want to disappear. The menu consists of a `Frame` packed with several `Label`/`Button` widgets. I can detect the user moving their mouse off a `Label`/`Button` with simply binding to the `<Enter>`/`<Leave` events for those. But binding to the same events for the frame never triggers - I guess because the widgets on top cover up the frame so the mouse never enters it?

Is their a way to make the events propagate down to the containing `Frame`?

```
window=tkinter.Tk()
menu_frm = tkinter.Frame(window, name="menu_frm")
lbl_1 = tkinter.Label(menu_frm, text="Label", name="lbl_1")
lbl_1.pack()
lbl_2 = tkinter.Label(menu_frm, text="Label", name="lbl_2")
lbl_2.pack()
menu_frm.pack()
# These two (per label and the number of labels is likely to grow) events fire
lbl_1.bind("<Enter>", lambda _: stayopenfunction())
lbl_1.bind("<Leave>", lambda _: closefunction())
lbl_2.bind("<Enter>", lambda _: stayopenfunction())
lbl_2.bind("<Leave>", lambda _: closefunction())
# These two events do not fire
menu_frm.bind("<Enter>", lambda _: stayopenfunction())
menu_frm.bind("<Leave>", lambda _: closefunction())
```

Comment: Posting the code snippet would help.

Comment: If the Label entirely covers the Frame, I don't see why you'd need to bind to the Frame also.  What do you want to happen that isn't happening?  BTW, you can simplify your bind syntax if you like: `lbl_1.bind("<Enter>" stayopenfunction)`

Comment: @saulspatz I've actually got several labels/buttons (I haven't decided if I will need both types yet) and so these events need binding to each one - this also means that if I want to change the function called I have to make sure I change it for every single one.

Comment: Your bindings work for me as expected (ie: events on the frame fire appropriately). Are you aware that your `menu_frm` does _not_ fill the whole window? It fits snug around the labels so it's almost impossible.

Comment: @BryanOakley I was hoping there might be a way in which events can propagate to their parent (like onclick events in javascript can be capturing or bubbling). I realise the frame fits snug around the labels, but was looking for the Enter/Leave event to trigger when entering/leaving the area covered by the frame (even if there is something else on top)

Comment: The frame _does_ get the enter/leave events. My point was, because the area the frame covers is so tiny, you might be thinking the event should fire when you enter/leave the window, but they only fire when you enter/leave the actual frame.

Comment: Ah yes, just tested again with several print statements and I see it is firing, but entering the label widget (contained in the frame) counts as leaving the frame - I was hoping this would still count as being inside the frame (and therefore moving the cursor onto the label would not trigger the frame's leave event)

Comment: @Kvothe - You enter and leave widgets individually. If you have a Label in a Frame, entering that Label does not mean you have left the Frame. You're in both. Arranging your '<Enter>' and '<Leave>' handlers properly will demonstrate that. For instance, printing out the widget names in your handlers will show that you can leave a Label but still be in the parent Frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to simplify maintenance of the callbacks on the widgets, then I don't think binding events to the containing frame is the best approach.  (I guess it's possible to generate virtual events in the callbacks on the buttons and labels, and bind the virtual event to the frame, but it seems rather complicated.  Maybe that's just because I have no experience with virtual events.)

Why not just subclass the label and button widgets?  Look at the "Instance and Class Bindings" heading at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm  Then you'd just have two class binding to maintain, one for the labels and one for the buttons.  This seems cleaner to me; it's just vanilla OOP.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the closest that exists to what I was looking for. I actually ended up assigning a <Button-1> event to the main window to close the menu if the click was off the menu. So the menu closes when the user clicks outside of it rather than just moves off it (like the Start button in Windows)

Answer (score 1):

I found an easy fix for what your trying to do, I was trying to do the same!

```
def function2(event):
    -revert event-
    Widget.bind("<Enter>", function1)
def function1(event):
    -hover event-
    Widget.bind("<Leave>", function2)
Widget.bind("<Enter>", function1)
```

Its a bit stupid, its not the best, but it just means that when you hover it does what its meant to and then listens for the event that reverts it, in this case ''.